# Breaking up a massive loop into multiple methods?

Tags: java

I have unfinished code for creating a litter of rabbits from a starting population.

I am trying to make my code more efficient by **breaking up my code into multiple methods instead of having a long `main`**.  But I do not know how to break my code up **without it breaking**. I am looking at the `main` code.

How could I break this up? I would like to have a method for tallying up the male and female rabbits. A method for doing the math for standard deviation and averages.

```java
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RabbitPractice {
    }public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Error, No File Exists. Program Stopping.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        if (!s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Error, No lines to read. Program Stopping.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

         while (s.hasNext()) {

            int[][] totals = new int[11][3];
            int females = s.nextInt();
            int males = s.nextInt();


            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                ArrayList<Rabbit> r = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int p = 0; p < females + males; p++) {
                    Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();
                    if (p < females) {
                        rabbit.setSex("F");
                    } else rabbit.setSex("M");
                    rabbit.setAge();
                    r.add(rabbit);
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < r.size(); z++) {
                        r.get(z).makeOlder();
                        if (r.get(z).isBirthed()) {
                            r.get(z).increaseLastLitter();
                        }
                        if (r.get(z).isPregnant()) {
                            r.get(z).increaseGestation();
                        }
                        if (r.get(z).itCanBreed()) {
                            r.get(z).breed();
                        }
                        if (r.get(z).itCanBreedAgain()) {
                            r.get(z).breed();
                        }
                        if (r.get(z).isPregnant() && r.get(z).itCanBirth()) {
                            r.get(z).birth();
                            for (int c = 0; c < r.get(z).getLitterSize(); c++) {
                                Rabbit baby = new Rabbit();
                                baby.setAge();
                                baby.setSex1();
                                r.add(baby);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                int m = 0;
                int f = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
                    if (r.get(i).getSex().equals("F")) {
                        f++;
                    } else if (r.get(i).getSex().equals("M")) {
                        m++;
                    }
                }
                totals[j][0] = r.size();
                totals[j][1] = f;
                totals[j][2] = m;
            }

            double averageTotal = 0;

            double averageMales = 0;

            double averageFemales = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                averageTotal += totals[i][0];
                System.out.println(averageTotal);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                averageFemales += totals[i][1];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                averageMales += totals[i][2];
            }


            double sumT = 0;
            double sumF = 0;
            double sumM = 0;
            averageTotal = averageTotal / 10;
            averageMales = averageMales / 10;
            averageFemales = averageFemales / 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                sumT += Math.pow(totals[i][0] - averageTotal,2);
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                sumF += Math.pow(totals[i][1] - averageFemales,2);
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                sumM += Math.pow(totals[i][2] - averageMales,2);
            }

            double stdT = 0;
            double stdF = 0;
            double stdM = 0;

            stdT += Math.sqrt(sumT/10);
            stdF += Math.sqrt(sumF/10);
            stdM += Math.sqrt(sumM/10);

            String middleLing = " was the final population of rabbits;";
            String stadDevLine = " with standard deviation of ";

            String doeS = " does, ";
            String bS = " bucks.";

            String shortenedTotal = String.format("%.3f", stdT);
            String shortenedMale = String.format("%.3f", stdM);
            String shortenedFemale = String.format("%.3f", stdF);

            System.out.println("Staring with "+females+" doe(s) and " + males + " buck(s):");
            System.out.println("Trial 1: "+totals[1][0]+middleLing+totals[1][1]+doeS+totals[1] . 
    [2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 2: "+totals[2][0]+middleLing+totals[2][1]+doeS+totals[2] 
    [2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 3: "+totals[3][0]+middleLing+totals[3][1]+doeS+totals[3] . 
    [2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 4: "+totals[4][0]+middleLing+totals[4][1]+doeS+totals[4] . 
    [2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 5: "+totals[5][0]+middleLing+totals[5][1]+doeS+totals[5][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 6: "+totals[6][0]+middleLing+totals[6][1]+doeS+totals[6][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 7: "+totals[7][0]+middleLing+totals[7][1]+doeS+totals[7][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 8: "+totals[8][0]+middleLing+totals[8][1]+doeS+totals[8][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 9: "+totals[9][0]+middleLing+totals[9][1]+doeS+totals[9][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Trial 10: "+totals[10][0]+middleLing+totals[10][1]+doeS+totals[10][2]+bS);
            System.out.println("Average number of rabbits: " + averageTotal + stadDevLine + shortenedTotal + ".");
            System.out.println("Average number of female rabbits: "+averageFemales+stadDevLine+shortenedFemale + ".");
            System.out.println("Average number of male rabbits: " + averageMales + stadDevLine + shortenedMale+ ".");
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't reviewed your code, but don't forget [Period Three Implies Chaos](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/LiYorke.pdf)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you have an easy-english summary of that article? Not exactly straightforward to read for my poor and simplistic brain.

Comment: @sp00m Sorry. Maybe start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) (the paper I linked to is summarized in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Density_of_periodic_orbits)).

Comment: You could at least put your prints in loops. My eyes hearts so much

Comment: Please give an example input & output for your program

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should spend some time on object-oriented programming lectures. This is what will help you most. As an example this is one possible way to split your code. But please note that its just an example and I did not take the time to reformulate, optimize nor improve code quality and clarity.

How you main method could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Error, No File Exists. Program Stopping.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    if (!s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Error, No lines to read. Program Stopping.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    List<ReadResults> readyLines = readLines(s);

    for (ReadResults readyLine : readyLines) {
        computeTotals(readyLine);
        Computations computations = doCompute(readyLine);
        showResults(computations, readyLine);
    }
}
```

It makes use of 2 classes which I embedded for simplicity (without getters/setters):

```
static class ReadResults {
    int[][] totals = new int[11][3];
    int males;
    int females;
}

static class Computations {
    double averageTotal = 0;
    double averageMales = 0;
    double averageFemales = 0;
    double sumT = 0;
    double sumF = 0;
    double sumM = 0;
    double stdT = 0;
    double stdF = 0;
    double stdM = 0;
}
```

And finally here is the splitted code logic:

```
protected static void showResults(Computations computations, ReadResults readyLine) {
    String middleLing = " was the final population of rabbits;";
    String stadDevLine = " with standard deviation of ";

    String doeS = " does, ";
    String bS = " bucks.";

    String shortenedTotal = String.format("%.3f", computations.stdT);
    String shortenedMale = String.format("%.3f", computations.stdM);
    String shortenedFemale = String.format("%.3f", computations.stdF);

    System.out.println("Staring with " + readyLine.females + " doe(s) and " + readyLine.males + " buck(s):");
    System.out.println("Trial 1: " + readyLine.totals[1][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[1][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[1][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 2: " + readyLine.totals[2][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[2][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[2][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 3: " + readyLine.totals[3][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[3][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[3][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 4: " + readyLine.totals[4][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[4][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[4][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 5: " + readyLine.totals[5][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[5][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[5][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 6: " + readyLine.totals[6][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[6][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[6][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 7: " + readyLine.totals[7][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[7][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[7][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 8: " + readyLine.totals[8][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[8][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[8][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 9: " + readyLine.totals[9][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[9][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[9][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Trial 10: " + readyLine.totals[10][0] + middleLing + readyLine.totals[10][1] + doeS + readyLine.totals[10][2] + bS);
    System.out.println("Average number of rabbits: " + computations.averageTotal + stadDevLine + shortenedTotal + ".");
    System.out.println("Average number of female rabbits: " + computations.averageFemales + stadDevLine + shortenedFemale + ".");
    System.out.println("Average number of male rabbits: " + computations.averageMales + stadDevLine + shortenedMale + ".");
    System.out.println();
}

protected static void computeTotals(ReadResults readyLine) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        ArrayList<Rabbit> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int p = 0; p < readyLine.females + readyLine.males; p++) {
            Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();
            if (p < readyLine.females) {
                rabbit.setSex("F");
            } else {
                rabbit.setSex("M");
            }
            rabbit.setAge();
            r.add(rabbit);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < r.size(); z++) {
                r.get(z).makeOlder();
                    if (r.get(z).isBirthed()) {
                        r.get(z).increaseLastLitter();
                    }
                    if (r.get(z).isPregnant()) {
                        r.get(z).increaseGestation();
                    }
                    if (r.get(z).itCanBreed()) {
                        r.get(z).breed();
                    }
                    if (r.get(z).itCanBreedAgain()) {
                        r.get(z).breed();
                    }
                if (r.get(z).isPregnant() && r.get(z).itCanBirth()) {
                        r.get(z).birth();
                    for (int c = 0; c < r.get(z).getLitterSize(); c++) {
                        Rabbit baby = new Rabbit();
                            baby.setAge();
                            baby.setSex1();
                        r.add(baby);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int m = 0;
        int f = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
            if (r.get(i).getSex().equals("F")) {
                f++;
            } else if (r.get(i).getSex().equals("M")) {
                m++;
            }
        }
        readyLine.totals[j][0] = r.size();
        readyLine.totals[j][1] = f;
        readyLine.totals[j][2] = m;
    }
}

protected static List<ReadResults> readLines(Scanner s) {
    List<ReadResults> reads = new ArrayList<>();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        ReadResults lineResults = new ReadResults();
        lineResults.females = s.nextInt();
        lineResults.males = s.nextInt();
    }
    return reads;    
}

protected static Computations doCompute(ReadResults readyLine) {
    Computations computations = new Computations();

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.averageTotal += readyLine.totals[i][0];
        System.out.println(computations.averageTotal);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.averageFemales += readyLine.totals[i][1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.averageMales += readyLine.totals[i][2];
    }

    computations.averageTotal = computations.averageTotal / 10;
    computations.averageMales = computations.averageMales / 10;
    computations.averageFemales = computations.averageFemales / 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.sumT += Math.pow(readyLine.totals[i][0] - computations.averageTotal, 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.sumF += Math.pow(readyLine.totals[i][1] - computations.averageFemales, 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        computations.sumM += Math.pow(readyLine.totals[i][2] - computations.averageMales, 2);
    }

    computations.stdT += Math.sqrt(computations.sumT / 10);
    computations.stdF += Math.sqrt(computations.sumF / 10);
    computations.stdM += Math.sqrt(computations.sumM / 10);

    return computations;
}
```